# Need to interpret JSON as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

First of all , I'm sorry my english is not good. I have a problem. I need to create a highchart from a ajax call.

This works perfect:

```
chartOptions = { chart: {  renderTo: 'grafica1', type: 'area', },  series: [{ data: [1,2,3] }]};
chartprueba = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
```

What im trying to do is an ajax with the message or json reponse like:

`"chart: {  renderTo: 'grafica1', type: 'area', },  series: [{ data: [1,2,3] }]}"`

So I need a way that jQuery interprets that like code no like string...

This is my example but doesn't work:

```
msg =  JSON.parse(msg);
chartOptions = msg;
chartprueba = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
```

Because `chartOptions` is an string not an object...

Comment: Tried `console.log`-ging your msg?

Comment: (and why not let jquery parse your json when doing ajax?)

Comment: how are you retrieving the json stored in msg? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: console.log(msg); print this -> { chart: {  renderTo: 'grafica1', type: 'area', },  series: [{ data: [1,2,3] }]}; ...

and console.log(chartOptions ) in the first example is Object {chart: Object, series: Array[1]} ... this is after parsing

Comment: Before or after parsing?

Comment: @Leandro Well, it probably doesn't work as the response isn't valid JSON. The output appears to use more of JavaScript's syntax options -- trailing commas in collections, identifiers as keys, single-quoted strings -- than JSON allows. You should try to fix that. Then, `JSON.parse(msg)` should work as expected.

Comment: i know is not a json format. I want to generate this -> 

chartOptions = { chart: {  renderTo: 'grafica1', type: 'area', },  series: [{ data: [1,2,3] }]}; 

but from php.

Comment: You do not want to generate this *string*, you want to pass this object. And using JSON is just a natural thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This string

```
"chart: { renderTo: 'grafica1', type: 'area', }, series: [{ data: [1,2,3] }]}"
```

is not a valid JSON. It has no opening curly brace, it has stray comma, keys aren't quoted. It is not even a valid javascript object definition, but check [`json.org`](http://json.org/) for additional strictness JSON imposes.

*EDIT:* Based on your comments elsewhere:

You're JSON-encoding *string*, not object. what you want is something like

```
$retorno = Array(
 chart => Array (renderTo =>'grafica1', type => 'area' ),
 series => Array(Array(data => Array(1,2,3)))
);
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

(if I remember `php` syntax right).

Comment: Based on the comments above, the leading `{` is only missing from the question text. So, it would be valid JavaScript at least.

Comment: i know that, what i was trying to do is to convert that string to be like the first example.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, yes, though for what I can tell by the comment to other answer, it's not just question text. And, again, JSON.parse (or at least most implementations) will still reject it as a json.

Comment: @Leandro, based on your comment to the other question, you're JSON-encoding *string*, not object. what you want is something like `$retorno = Array( chart => Array (renderTo =>'grafica1', type => 'area' }, series => Array(Array(data => Array(1,2,3)))); echo json_encode($retorno)`.

Comment: perfect! I have just change to array and works perfect. Thanks a lot Michael Krelin!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should try to update the server-side resource to output the `Object` as valid JSON.

```
{ "chart": { "renderTo": "grafica1", "type": "area" }, ... }
```

And, then `JSON.parse()` should be fine:

```
msg = JSON.parse(msg);
```

---

Based on the snippet from [your other comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19502992#comment28930512_19503107):

```
$retorno = " chart: { renderTo: 'grafica1', type: 'area', }, series: [{ data: [1,2,3] }]";
echo json_encode($retorno);
return;
```

You can use [Michael Krelin's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19502992#comment28930674_19503141) of forming your data in [`array()`s](http://php.net/array) and encoding that:

```
$retorno = array(
    'chart' => array(
        'renderTo' => 'grafica1',
        'type' => 'area'
    ),

    'series' => array(
        array('data' => array(1, 2, 3))
    )
);

echo json_encode($retorno);
return;
```

Associative arrays (those with named keys) in PHP will encode as `Object`s in JSON while non-associative will remain as `Array`s.

---

Otherwise, you're left with having to [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) `msg`:

```
msg = eval('(' + msg + ')');
```

If the output is missing the leading `{`, add it as well:

```
msg = eval('({' + msg + ')');
```

And, the parenthesis force it to be evaluated as an *Expression*, so `{...}` are treated as `Object` literals rather than [`blocks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Comment: I'd even say `'({'` if fixing the server is not an option ;)

Comment: Never ever do this, if your json can be manipulated by user! If you really want to eval, sanitize first.

Comment: Yeees! You solve it. that solve my problem. should i try to change all to a json? Its the best way to do it right?

Comment: @Frizi I'm not suggesting it's a good idea. Just that it seems to be the 1 option remaining.

Comment: thanks all! Im very new with javascript. I will try to change all to json.

Comment: While this answer is perfectly fine, please do read my last reply to you under my answer.

Comment: Now this answer is even perfectly finer, +1 ;)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Oh. Sorry. Somehow didn't realize you'd answered with it. Thought the snippet was just in comments so was trying to bump up its visibility.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, that was the right decision and I +1-ed your answer since it had all the information. I was perfectly fine with checkmark being on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in jQuery called `$.parseJSON`, this will return an object, created from the data.

So if you had JSON like: `{'val1': 0}`
you could run `var data = $.parseJSON({'val1': 0});`, this would then give you the ability to get the values through an object.

e.g.

`data.val1`

Hope this helps,

‐ Sid

here is the [link to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know this, but my problem i think its a little bigger. Im passing a string from php, not a json. 
Look this is my php code 

$retorno = " chart: {  renderTo: 'grafica1', type: 'area', }, series: [{ data: [1,2,3] }]";
echo json_encode($retorno);
return;

Comment: thats true Kevin B. What im trying to do is to generate the chartOptions from php.

Comment: JSON is always a string, it's just a shorthand for JavaScript Object Notation, you can also parse this string into `$.parseJSON`